# Corrupt files on shared folder virtualbox ubuntu guest on mac osx

Tags: network-shares, virtualbox

I'm having this annoying issue with a shared folder on a Mac OS X host, and Ubuntu 11.10 guest.  I have a shared folder beetween them.  Most of the time when creating a folder, copying files, or renaming files on the host folder, I get errors on the Ubuntu guest.  For instance, I just renamed the file PurchaseController.php from Purchase.php on Mac OS X NetBeans IDE, and on the ubuntu guest this is the `ls -l` output:

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 170 Feb 18 21:42 ./
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 170 Feb 18 16:32 ../
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 238 Feb 18 16:43 .svn/
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 125 Feb 18 16:44 IndexController.php*
?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? PurchasesController.php
```

The Zend Framework application running on that guest won't read the file PurchasesController.php.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a question for ServerFault - It needs to be moved to SuperUser.  Also, Google says you're not alone; https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=46549

Comment: oops, sorry about that, ... yeah I lookd that forum entry today ,... there's a workaround ...